# struggling with Import Sys

Tags: python

I'm brand new to coding and I'm trying to get my code to work in the command line so that when I type **python3 filename.py The World is big** - it returns the the first smallest word on the next lines.

I know that I'm over-thinking this but I really need a dummies version of how to know where to put the sys.argv to make this work.  I'll put a very simple code that I have tried different ways and just don't know where to put it.   I have to enter the string on the line before it gives me the answer.

```
import sys

text = input("")

short = min(text.split(), key=len)

print("Shortest word is: ", short)
```

Comment: Replace the `input("")` part. Notice to `""` your input "The World is big" to prevent shell splitting.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. `argv[0]` is the script name.

So you could directly get the inputs from `sys.argv`. E.g.

```py
import sys

print(sys.argv)

# python filename.py "The World is big"
# prints:
# ['filename.py', 'The World is big']
```

Note that the arguments passed in the example above is quoted, making it a single string argument. Running `python filename.py The World is big` would pass each word as a single argument.

```py
# python filename.py The World is big
# prints:
# ['filename.py', 'The', 'World', 'is', 'big']
```